# feedback sent but not shown neither in google play developer console nor in firebase crashlitics

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-crash-reporting

I am developing a react-native application with react-native-google-signin package.

When the app is released I get a crash during google signing in, and I send the feedback to the developer (The device tells me that the feedback is sent correctly).

I do not know why I do not see the error neither in google play developer console nor in the firebase crashlitics console (I also added it to check better errors).